# elseif statement containing multiple expressions separated by -or failing

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script which is basically a simple calculator. The script needs to be passed 3 parameters, the first one being a number, the second one being an arithmetic operator (+ - * /) and the third one being another number, after which the script returns the calculated value.

Initially, the script worked being like this:

```psh
param (
  [double]$num1,
  [string]$op,
  [double]$num2
)

switch ($op) {
  "+" {write-host $($num1+$num2)}
  "-" {write-host $($num1-$num2)}
  "*" {write-host $($num1*$num2)}
  "/" {write-host $($num1/$num2)}
}
```

However, I want to make the script a bit more complex by throwing a different error message for each of these situations:

1. When no parameters are passed, the message would be *"You haven't specified any parameters"*.
2. When the second parameter isn't either "+", "-", "*" or "/", the message would be 
   *"You haven't specified a valid operator (+ - * /) as the second parameter"*.
3. When the previous 2 situations don't occur but no third parameter (the 2nd number) is passed, the message would be *"You haven't specified the second number"*.

So, with this in mind, I made some changes to the script ending up like this:

```psh
param (
  [double]$num1,
  [string]$op,
  [double]$num2
)

if ($num1 -eq "") {
  write-host "You haven't specified any parameters"
} elseif (($op -ne "+") -or ($op -ne "-") -or ($op -ne "*") -or ($op -ne "/")) {
  write-host "You haven't specified a valid operator (+ - * /) as the second parameter"
} elseif ($num2 -eq "") {
  write-host "You haven't specified the second number"
} else {
  switch ($op) {
    "+" {write-host $($num1+$num2)}
    "-" {write-host $($num1-$num2)}
    "*" {write-host $($num1*$num2)}
    "/" {write-host $($num1/$num2)}
  }
}
```

So now, if I don't pass any parameters to the script, I get the *"You haven't specified any parameters"* message.

If I only pass the first parameter, I get the *"You haven't specified a valid operator (+ - * /) as the second parameter"*, which is good.

But if I pass the first parameter and, as the second parameter I pass either "+", "-", "*" or "/", I still get the *"You haven't specified a valid operator (+ - * /) as the second parameter"* message so there's something wrong in the first `elseif` statement, although it seems to be syntactically-correct.

Comment: Why not make it an advanced function, and take care of all of that using parameter validation in the Param block?

Comment: True, but I haven't learned how to do that yet, so I decided to try it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use Advanced Function Parameter Options

The solution mjolinor is suggesting (in his comment) would look something like this:

```powershell
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [double]
    $num1,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [ValidateSet('+', '-', '*', '/')]
    [string]
    $op,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [double]
    $num2
)

    switch ($op) {
           "+" {write-host $($num1+$num2)}
           "-" {write-host $($num1-$num2)}
           "*" {write-host $($num1*$num2)}
           "/" {write-host $($num1/$num2)}
    }
```

This has the added benefit of letting you tab complete the operator.

## Your Solution

The reason yours isn't working is because you're using `-or` when you should be using `-and`:

```powershell
elseif (($op -ne "+") -and ($op -ne "-") -and ($op -ne "*") -and ($op -ne "/"))
```

It can get confusing because of the fact that you're checking for the negative condition (i.e. `if (an_invalid_value)`) where the conditions inside are negated (`-ne`).

Consider what happens in your version if you choose minus `-`: You evaluate `$op -ne '+'` and this is true, so condition satisfied, nothing else is tested, you go right to telling the user they did the wrong thing. With `-and`, *all* of the `-ne` conditions would need to be satisfied.

Here's an even simpler way of doing it your way:

```powershell
elseif ( ('+','-','*','/') -notcontains $op)
```

Basically you say "if this array of operators does not contain `$op`, then display the error." It's much easier to follow.

But what's really much easier, and safer, and maintainable, is to use the built-in parameter validation options. Learn them; they're great!

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution and what a great answer...thanks !! I'll keep an eye on the built-in parameter validation options but I do prefer this format

Answer (score 1):

Think about your condition statement:

```
elseif (($op -ne "+") -or ($op -ne "-") -or ($op -ne "*") -or ($op -ne "/"))
```

The -or means if any of them are true, then the whole test is true.
What you want is for the whole test to be true only if all of them are true.

What can you do to fix that?

Comment: Change the -or's for -and's...but someone has already said it. Nevertheless, thanks for the hint !